# Dompdf fails on create output documents if tablecells contains rowspan

Tags: html-table, dompdf

If my html document has cells with tag rowspan, dompdf cannot create document.
Any idea?
Thanks

```
<table>
...
    <tr>
        <td >           
        Marc conceptual i metodol&ograve;gic
        </td>
        <td >25</td>
        <td rowspan="2" >15</td>
        <td rowspan="2" >15</td>
        <td rowspan="3" >45</td>
    </tr>
...
```

Comment: The problem is unlikely due to just the rowspan. It would help to see some sample HTML that reproduces the problem.

Comment: The issue more than likely is that the rowspan "Spans" multiple pages.  This is a known issue of Dompdf